# Clarity on Testing subclass init method

Tags: python, unit-testing, inheritance, abstract-class, init

I am new to Object-oriented. 
I am trying to test my RightPyramid init method, not sure if there's a way I can do this as my
RightPyramid init doesn't have any arguments.

```
from typing import List
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Triangle(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, base: int, height: int) -> None:
        assert base >= 0, "base must be greater or equal to 0"
        assert height >= 0, "height must be greater or equal to 0"
        self.base = base
        self.height = height

    @abstractmethod
    def area(self) -> int:   
        pass


class RightPyramid(Triangle):
    def __init__(self):
        Triangle.__init__(self, 3, 2)

    def area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base + self.height
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instead you want to test your Triangle base class behavior you should create new class :

```py
class TestInit(Triangle):
    def __init__(self):
        Triangle.__init__(self, -3, 2) # this should throw an assertion fail

t = TestInit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To test RightPyramid, Executing the following code:

```py
rp = RightPyramid()
```

will actually call the RightPyramid.__init__() method, with self replaced by the instance and returned in the rp variable.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say i change the value of my base to -3 I want my superclass to throw an exception as the base is less than 0.